# Prevent/Allow Form From Submitting

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am Trying To Prevent/Allow the form from submitting using certain conditions given in the js below. I am able to get all the responses from my php code and and display them but the if condition which Prevents/Allows the form to be Submitted seems to be now working as it is supposed to be. there is a delay in getting the responses from the php though. the if condition is satisfied only if the responses are "OK" but the if Condition is Processed before i Get The responses from the php code.

Please Help

Thank You.

JS --

```
function checkall() {
var name=document.getElementById( "UserName" ).value;
var email=document.getElementById( "UserEmail" ).value;
var group=document.getElementById( "GroupName" ).value;

if(name)
{
$.ajax({
type: 'post',
url: 'checkdata.php',
data: {
user_name:name,
},
success: function (response) {
$( '#name_status' ).html(response);
}
});
}
else
{
$( '#name_status' ).html("");
}

if(email)
{
$.ajax({
type: 'post',
url: 'checkdata.php',
data: {
user_email:email,
},
success: function (response) {
   $( '#email_status' ).html(response);
  }
 });
}
else
{
   $( '#email_status' ).html("");
   return false;
}


if(group)
{
 $.ajax({
  type: 'post',
  url: 'checkdata.php',
  data: {
    groupname:group,
  },
success: function (response) {
   $( '#group_status' ).html(response);
  }
 });
}
else
{
$( '#group_status' ).html("");
return false;
}

var namehtml=document.getElementById("name_status").innerHTML;
var emailhtml=document.getElementById("email_status").innerHTML;
var grouphtml=document.getElementById("group_status").innerHTML;

if((namehtml && emailhtml && grouphtml)=="OK")
  {
   alert("processing");
   return true;
  } else {
   alert("Failed To Submit");             
   return false;
  }

//return false;
}
```

Html --

```
<form name="registration" action="" method="post" onsubmit="return checkall()" autocomplete="off">
    <input type="text" name="username" required="required" id="UserName" />
    <label for="#{label}">Username</label> <p id="name_status"></p>


    <input type="email" name="email" required="required" id="UserEmail" />
    <label for="#{label}">Email</label> <p id="email_status"></p>



    <input type="password" id="#{label}" name="password" required="required"/>
    <label for="#{label}">Admin Password</label>



    <input type="text" name="group_name" required="required" id="GroupName" />
    <label for="#{label}">Group Name</label> <p id="group_status"></p>



    <input type="password" id="#{label}" name="group_password" required="required"/>
    <label for="#{label}">Group Password</label>



    <button type="submit" id="myBtn" name="submit"><span>Next</span></button>

</form>
```

Comment: There are probably several ways to handle this, but if you only want to submit the form based on certain conditions then you can change the submit button to a regular button (using type="button"), wiring its onclick event to any JavaScript method you choose, and then having that method decide whether to submit the form or not.

Comment: @RobZuber I did what you said but the problem is the if statement which decides to submit or not is being processed before the php response. The php response takes time as it has to pass sql query and verify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a nutshell, your PHP call is async, but your onSubmit() is synchronous.

So, you have to find a way to make `onSubmit()` behave in a more synchronous manner.

The basic way to do that would be:

- On submit, call your PHP function and return false.

  - Ideally, also disable your submit button so people wouldn't hit it again.
- When your call completes, if it was valid, manually submit the form.

  - You can form.submit() or something similar, depending on your exact framework. Looks like you're using jQuery, so `$('form').submit()` would do the trick.
- If it wasn't valid, do whatever validation displaying you want to do.

  - Enable your submit button again for subsequent calls if you disabled it earlier.

By returning false right away, you are telling the form to not submit. However, that then gives you all the time you need to just sit and wait until your PHP returns. You can then manually trigger the submit if it works, or not if it didn't. Thus, you've made your form behave like it is async.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but Should i define a new php function or the function which does the registration process.

Comment: Figured it out Thanks